# How to deal with dependent fields while serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I don't understand the general principles of how to deal with dependent fields while serializing classes.

There are many patterns where fields appear dependent on each other. For example, below I am creating an observable wrapper for a list in constructor. When creating, wrapper takes dependency field and wraps it.

This class is not deserialized both in `Gson` and default `Java` deserializer.

In `Gson` it calls default constructor, which establishes link first. But later `Gson` creates new instance for `delegate` member, which breaks the link, since `observable` now refers obsolete object.

I don't understand, what for does `Gson` creators call default constructor, if they later discard it's function? Do they think that every class can survive direct field assignment?

Java default serialization also does not work. They just ignores transient field and it remains null. Constructor is not called.

I also don't understand: if they doesn't call constructor, then why didn't they assume `Serializable` interface having some constructor-equivalent method, which should be called after deserializtion?

```
package tests;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonIOException;

public class Try05 {

    public static class MyList implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7048098048856503023L;

        ArrayList<Integer> delegate = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        transient ObservableList<Integer> observable = FXCollections.observableList(delegate);

        public void add(int value) {
            observable.add(value);
        }

        public int sum() {
            int ans = 0;
            for (Integer i : observable) {
                ans += i.intValue();
            }
            return ans;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return delegate.toString();
        }

    }

    public static void tryGson() throws JsonIOException, IOException {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().setVersion(1.0)
                .create();

        MyList list = new MyList();

        list.add(12);
        list.add(13);

        System.out.println(String.format("list = %s, sum = %d", list.toString(), list.sum()));
        System.out.println(String.format("hash = %d", System.identityHashCode(list.delegate)));

        File file = File.createTempFile("list", ".json");

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        gson.toJson(list, writer);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        list = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(file), MyList.class);

        list.add(14);

        System.out.println(String.format("list = %s, sum = %d", list.toString(), list.sum()));
        System.out.println(String.format("hash = %d", System.identityHashCode(list.delegate)));

    }

    public static void tryBuiltin() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        MyList list = new MyList();

        list.add(12);
        list.add(13);

        System.out.println(String.format("list = %s, sum = %d", list.toString(), list.sum()));
        System.out.println(String.format("hash = %d", System.identityHashCode(list.delegate)));

        File file = File.createTempFile("list", ".json");

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        out.writeObject(list);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        list = (MyList) in.readObject();

        list.add(14);

        System.out.println(String.format("list = %s, sum = %d", list.toString(), list.sum()));
        System.out.println(String.format("hash = %d", System.identityHashCode(list.delegate)));

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            tryGson();

            tryBuiltin();

        } catch (JsonIOException | IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement about the `Serializable` interface not containing a method called on deserialisation was incorrect - there is; using default java serialization, you can declare a special method that will be invoked on reading your object. It looks like this:

```
private /* or any other access modifier */ void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException {
    // your code here
}
```

In this case, the contents of this method would look like this:

```
in.defaultReadObject(); // invoke default read
observable = FXCollections.observableList(delegate); // initialise observable
```

For more information on this method and others, look at the specification of the `Serializable` class:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html